# pass string array value from controller to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

How to pass string array value from controller to view? i got this error "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

```
@for(int i =0 ; i< 2; i ++)
{
   <div class=" col-md-3">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Overnight[i], new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
   </div>
}
```

### model

```
public string[] Overnight{ get; set; }
```

### controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    model.Overnight = new string[] {"A" };
    model.Overnight = new string[] {"b" };
}
```

Comment: Your adding only one element to the array (the 2nd line in your controller overwrites the 1st). And use `for(int i = 0; i < Model.Overnight.Length; i++)`

Comment: `model.Overnight = new string[] {"b" }`; is the culprit - you've only one text element here, so the index is out of bounds. You should use `model.Overnight = new string[] {"A", "b" };`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do these lines:

```
model.Overnight = new string[] {"A" };
model.Overnight = new string[] {"b" };
```

You are not adding `"B"` to an array with the value of `"A"` but creating a new array only with `"B"` and assigning it to the `Overnight` property, instead of the array that was there. Therefor when your loop iterates until `i < 2` then it works for `i = 0` but for `i = 1` there is no such item in the array and you get `OutOfBounds`.
What you want is to do:

```
model.Overnight = new string[] {"A", "B"};

//or
model.Overnight = new string[] {"A"};
model.Overnight.Add("B");
```

---

In addition do not define your loop as you did:

```
@for(int i = 0 ; i < 2; i++)
```

exactly for the reason yo encountered. Instead loop until `i < model.Overnight.Length`